# Что делает конструкция (obj.f = obj.f)() и почему при ее использовании теряется контекст вызова?

Tags: javascript

```
function foo() {
  return this;
}

let bar = {
  foo
};

console.log(
  foo(),

  bar.foo(),
  (bar.foo)(),

  (bar.foo = bar.foo)(), // здесь
);
```

Собственно, понятно, почему `bar.foo()` вернет `bar`. Почему `(bar.foo)()` вернет `bar` - тоже. А вот почему теряется контекст в последнем выражении - вообще непонятно.

Непонятно также, что делает такая конструкция. Что она в конечном итоге вызывает? Левый операнд или правый? (Понятно, что в данном конкретном случае разницы нет, но я говорю про общий случай).

Comment: @Grundy не содержится в "дубликате" ответа на мой вопрос. Ни на один из них.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo()` - вызов функции в глобальном контексте (тут все просто)

`bar.foo()` - вызов метода объекта `bar` - JS создал для вас ключи у объекта (вообще так создавать объекты не есть хорошо, но JS решил что это должно выглядеть так `{foo: foo, baz: baz}`). См. [короткая нотация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2)

`(bar.foo)()` - то же самое что и в прошлом случае

`(bar.foo = bar.foo)()` - тут интереснее - мы вызываем не метод объекта, а глобальную функцию, которая является результатом выражения в скобках. То есть мы берем значение поля - которое является функцией и присваиваем другому полю (в данном случае они одинаковые), но результатом будет именно эта функция а не поле (поскольку последней операцией в скобках было присваивание, а не разыменование метода)

**Дополнение**

Если выполнить пример в строгом режиме - при потере контекста получим `undefined`. См [this в контексте функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#%D0%92_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Вот не знаю: слово _"глобальную"_ может кого-то смутить и заставить думать, что такое происходит, только если функция объявлена вне объекта?

Comment: "не метод объекта, а глобальную функцию" - тогда что насчет предыдущего примера?

Comment: @Regent исправлю, хотя нет - не исправлю. Функция без контекста вызывается в глобальном контексте

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вся беда кроется в том, что оператор присваивания возвращает функцию (контекст которой, понятное дело, потерян)? Которая потом и вызывается (уже без контекста).

Comment: @smellyshovel Да. Из правой части мы берем только функцию (контекста нет) ее значение помещаем в переменную, указанную в левой части присваивания, но результатом операции присваивания является как раз правая часть

Comment: @tutankhamun в итоге в ответе можно оставить только то, что значение `this` - динамическое, поэтому теряется контекст при присвоении функции новой переменной и то, что вызывается правая часть.

Comment: Но в целом спасибо, вроде понял, что к чему.

Comment: Кстати, заметил, что предыдущая строка (`(bar.foo)()`) тоже возвращает window. С чем это может быть связано? Может быть как-нибудь со `strict mode`'ом?

Comment: @smellyshovel тоже про него вспомнил :)

Comment: @tutankhamun да, но тут одна маленькая загвоздочка возникает: почему 2 последних примера выдают `window` и `undefined` соответственно (в стрикт моде), а не `undefined` оба раза?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71473/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and-smellyshovel).